# Fontshapes undefined when installing ttf font with autoinst TexLive on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pdftex, texlive, ubuntu

I'm trying to use a TrueType Font with Texlive (3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian))
via autoinst on Ubuntu 20.04. Even though autoinst creates all the files and shapes correctly I still can't get the different font shapes to work and get the following error.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/OpenSans/m/it' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

To illustrate the problem I use Open Sans (available here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?preview.text_type=custom). When I run

```
sudo autoinst *.ttf
```

in the download folder, autoinst runs as expected. The log-file looks like this:

```
[2021-03-19 17:16:28]  /usr/bin/autoinst, version 20200129

    "/usr/bin/autoinst OpenSans-Bold.ttf OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf OpenSans-Italic.ttf OpenSans-Light.ttf OpenSans-Regular.ttf OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf"

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'm using the following options:

    encoding(s):        OT1, LY1, T1
    NFSS:               sf (sanserif)

    lining:             yes
    oldstyle:           yes
    proportional:       yes
    tabular:            yes
    ts1:                yes
    smallcaps:          yes
    swash:              yes
    titling:            yes
    superiors:          yes
    inferiors:          none
    ornaments:          yes
    fractions:          no
    ligatures:          yes

    auto/manual:        auto
    target:             /home/ird/Downloads/OpenSans/autoinst_output
    extra:              

    figurekern:         keep
    mergewidths:        yes
    mergeweights:       yes
    mergeshapes:        yes

    nfssweight:         
    nfsswidth:          

    


----------------------------------------------------------------------------

NFSS mappings:

    ul  =>  
    el  =>  
    l   =>  light
    sl  =>  
    m   =>  regular
    sb  =>  semibold
    b   =>  bold
    eb  =>  extrabold
    ub  =>  

    uc  =>  
    ec  =>  
    c   =>  
    sc  =>  
    m   =>  regular
    sx  =>  
    x   =>  
    ex  =>  
    ux  =>
```

Copying the created folders to my working *texmf-dist* folder and running *sudo texhash* and  *sudo updmap -sys* I can run pdflatex on the following file

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{OpenSans}

\begin{document}

This is supposed to be Open Sans, but is Computer Modern.

I can change the font manually by {\fontfamily{OpenSans}\selectfont to be OpenSans.}

But I can make it {\fontfamily{OpenSans}\fontshape{it}\selectfont to be italic.}

\end{document}
```

The errors I'm getting are

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/OpenSans/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/OpenSans/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/OpenSans/m/n' instead on input line 13.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/t1fvs.fd) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pbk.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./General_Notes.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Any pointers what is going here and what I'm doing wrong? It seems like the *OpenSans.sty* file isn't working, but Latex isn't complaining or throwing any other errors.

Many thanks!

Comment: where is T1opensans.fd and what is its content?

Comment: Thanks Ulrike for getting back.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ulrike for getting back. There isn't really a T1openssans.fd created in the process but files that are called T1OpenSans-LF.fd or similar and are located in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/OpenSans/T1OpenSans-OsF.fd

[image]

The contents of T1OpenSans-LF.fd look like this:

```
%% Generated by autoinst on 2021/03/20
%%
\ProvidesFile{T1OpenSans-LF.fd}
    [2021/03/20 (autoinst)  Font definitions for T1/OpenSans-LF.]

\expandafter\ifx\csname OpenSans@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\OpenSans@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\OpenSans@@scale{s*[\csname OpenSans@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{l}{n}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-Light-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{l}{it}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-LightItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{l}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/l/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{eb}{n}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-ExtraBold-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{eb}{it}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{eb}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/eb/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{sb}{it}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{sb}{n}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-SemiBold-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{sb}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/sb/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-Regular-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-Italic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{m}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/m/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{b}{n}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-Bold-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{b}{it}{
      <-> \OpenSans@@scale OpenSans-BoldItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{b}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/b/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{bx}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/b/sl
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{bx}{n}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/b/n
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{OpenSans-LF}{bx}{it}{
      <-> ssub * OpenSans-LF/b/it
}{}

\endinput
```

Comment: I actually have not tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and everything works like a charm. Has anyone experienced issues with autoinst created fonts on 20.04?